# Redux - how to call an action creator from inside another action creator?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the following action creator:

```
export function foo(param) {
    ...
}
```

and I want to call it from an adjacent action creator (in the same file) like this:

```
export function bar(param){
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch({
            type: ATYPE.SET_DO_THIS_BEFORE_FOO,
            payload: param
        });

        foo(param);
    }
}
```

but the `foo` action creator is not firing from inside `bar`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Simply to re-use the action creators functions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to your example, it seems that you're already using `redux-thunk`. If that's the case, the only thing that you're forgetting is to dispatch the action created by your action creator:

```
dispatch(foo(param));
```